# Showing trajectory of a dynamics on the unit ball

Tags: plotting, physics

I have a unit ball and a vector with r0x, r0y and r0z ,the x,y,z components at initial time which evolves to r2x, r2y and r2z as function of time. I want to show the trajectory as in the attached figure here.

```
density2={{0.75, 0.25 - 0.25 I}, {0.25 + 0.25 I, 0.25}};

density2t = {{0.75,0.5 (0.5 (1. E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.1 t]-1. E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.1 t])-(0. +0.5 I) (1. E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.1 t]+1. E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.1 t]))},{0.5 (0.5 (1. E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.1 t]-1. E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.1 t])+(0. +0.5 I) (1. E^(0.2 t) Cos[0.1 t]+1. E^(0.2 t) Sin[0.1 t])),0.25}};

r0x = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[1]]//FullSimplify
r0y = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[2]]//FullSimplify
r0z = Tr[density2.PauliMatrix[3]]//FullSimplify

r2x = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[1]] // FullSimplify
r2y = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[2]] // FullSimplify
r2z = Tr[density2t.PauliMatrix[3]] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: `{r2x, r2y, r2z}` is a vector with real components as a function of time. However, `{r0x, r0y, r0z}` have a real and complex part. I think you need an intial vector that has only real components. The way it is written, `r2z` has a constant value of 0.5, is that what you intended?

Comment: @Jack LaVigne, What you say is wrong. {r0x,r0y,r0z} has only real component. All are equal to 0.5. Just by looking at density2, how can you say this? Evaluate and see.

Comment: It is true in a sense that, for example, `r0x` is real because the imaginary component is zero. However, if you execute `Head[r0x]`, Mathematica returns Complex. I wouldn't worry about it, your comment makes it clear that `0.5` for the value is your intent. I have further questions which I have placed in the extended comment below.

Comment: Jyothi, why did you remove the figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I now understand the question you are not so much interested in the curve, but rather how to plot a curved line with a unit sphere mesh of circles in the Z-axis.

You will have to use a new curve for the example because if you allow two rotations at the current frequency of `0.1 t` (i.e, `t = 40 π`) the magnitude of the vector is way beyond the unit sphere.

```
Norm[{r2x, r2y, r2z} /. t -> 40 π]
(* 5.81428*10^10 *)
```

### Example curve

So I will define an example curve as follows:

```
b=2.5;
t0=1;

r2x = Exp[b (t - t0)] (0.5 Cos[4 π t] - 0.5 Sin[4 π t]);
r2y = Exp[b (t - t0)] (0.5 Cos[4 π t] + 0.5 Sin[4 π t]);
r2z = 0.0;
```

Next we define some graphics to plot it.

Create the curve.

```
vectorPath = ParametricPlot3D[
  {r2x, r2y, r2z}, 
  {t, 0, 1.15},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
  PlotStyle -> Black,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  Axes -> False,
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  ]
```

the axes

```
axes = Graphics3D[
  {
   Thin,
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.1, 0, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.1, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1.1}}],
   Text[Style["x", 14], {1.1, 0, -0.1}],
   Text[Style["y", 14], {0.1, 1.1, 0}],
   Text[Style["z", 14], {0.1, 0, 1.1}]
   }
  ]
```

The unit sphere is the item of interest. We set `Mesh` to a list of `{11,0}` to get uniformly spaced horizontal mesh and no vertical mesh. A light gray is used for the `Mesh` and the `Opacity` set to zero.

```
unitSphere = ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
   Cos[θ]},
  {θ, 0, Pi},
  {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotRange -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]],
  Mesh -> {11, 0},
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  ]
```

Now we put all this together using `Show` to plot it.

```
Show[
 vectorPath,
 axes,
 unitSphere
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The pink circles have no particular significance. I am using ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], 
   Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], Mesh -> 11, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]; to create the unit ball with a mesh appearance, that's all. The black curve is the solution of a trajectory obtained by solving an equation. I shall update the question with the details of the equation asap. Many thanks, once again.

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to indicate the initial(starting point) of the trajectory by a red dot or something like that?

Comment: Create `point = Graphics3D[
  {
   PointSize[0.025],
   Red,
   Point[{r2x, r2y, r2z} /. t -> 0]
   }
  ]` and add it to the `Show`

Comment: Many thanks for the idea.